# Command Pattern in turn-based card game

Tags: java, design-patterns, client-server, command-pattern

I am trying to build a small multi-client/server turn-based card game.  I am utilising the Command Pattern to update my 'GameInstance' objects which hold the entire game state (game deck, discard pile, all players [which in-turn hold their own hands], etc.)

My base command looks like such:

```
public interface IGameCommand extends Serializable {
    public abstract boolean isValid();
    public abstract void execute();
}
```

So, when the client (which has a reference to 'GameInstance') creates a concrete command, say, "DrawCardCommand" it looks like such:

```
public class DrawCardCommand extends GameCommand {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4815250478595425060L;
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DrawCardCommand.class);

/***
 * opponent = player making command, GameInstance = game to apply changes to
 */
public DrawCardCommand(Opponent opponent, GameInstance instance){
    super(opponent, instance);
}

@Override
public boolean isValid() {

    // the super (abstract) class will verify that the 
    // player making the command, actually has control of
    // game play and that the game status is 'in-play'
    if(!super.isValid()){
        return false;
    }

    // game must be 'WAITING_FOR_DRAW' status
    if(this.instance.getStatus().compareTo(GameStatus.WAITING_FOR_DRAW) != 0){
        return false;
    }

    // are there cards in the deck to draw from?
    if(this.instance.getDeck().getCardCount() < 1){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void execute() {
    // draw the top card from the deck
    ICard drawnCard = this.instance.getDeck().drawFromTop();

    // get the drawn card and give it to the current player
    IPlayerConfig player =  this.instance.getPlayerConfig(this.currentPlayer);

    if(null == player){
        log.error(String.format("Failed during execute. PlayerConfig not found for player %s in game %d",
                                this.currentPlayer.toString(),
                            this.instance.getInstanceId()));
        return;
    }

    // place the drawn card in the players hand
    player.getHand().placeOnBottom(drawnCard);

    // update the status of the game (waiting for player
    // to negotiate)
    this.instance.setStatus(GameStatus.WAITING_FOR_OFFER);  
}
```

So, when the client creates this concrete command, it calls `isValid()` and then `execute()` if the command is valid, which updates the `GameInstance` object passed into the DrawCardCommand constructor.

My question is:  Once the player (client) has applied the command to THEIR game state, and I send the command over the wire to the server. How do I apply those changes (using this Command pattern) to the server-side game state?

I can't just grab it and re-apply it, as calling `execute()` again would redo the 'move'.

Should I not apply the command on the client side? only validate the move and then send it to the server?

And, where should I place the code to update the database? (I have a DAO layer). Surely, not in the execute() method as it would have not context on the client-side --- only on the server-side?

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: I would make `GameInstance` a lightweight proxy that reflects the server's game state.  Anything you carry out on the `GameInstance` should actually be making those changes to the server's state instead of maintaining two copies (read states could be maintained locally if you were concerned about performance)

Comment: Let's say the client logs in and is immediately handed a proxy by the server, the client then plays their turn creating a DrawCardCommand (which has a reference to the proxy).  Does the client first give the command to a local invoker to call execute() and then send it to the server? Wouldn't the server have to somehow call execute() again to apply them to the ACTUAL gameinstance (not the proxy).  So, the proxy would store an additional copy of the gameinstance? (1 for the client to modify, and an untouched copy for application on the server side?)  Sorry If I am over complicating this...

Comment: No. The local instance would do nothing but forward the request to the server and, if required, pass any return value back to the client.  It just acts as a middle man and manages the protocol which enables the client and server to talk with each other, it carries no information about the state of the game.  Every call the client makes to the proxy is passed directly to the server to be handled there...

Comment: Ah! So, the client will actually only ever display the gameinstance data that comes from the server.  If I understand correctly, the client will generate the Command object, it gets sent over the wire to the server, where it will invoke the isValid() and execute().  In the execute() I should place the db update code (via DAO) and return to the client a refreshed gameinstance proxy object.  Correct?

Comment: For me, I would carry only the information required to carry information back and forth from the client and server (just so we are clear) and maintain the entire game state on the server.  So, when the client wants to do something it would make a "request" to server which would carry out the request and send any responses it might need to back.  Equally, when the client wanted to know something, it would request that information from the server, so no game state information is maintained by the client at all, just so we're clear ;)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I see too many question marks for it to be one question. Have you considered splitting it up till you have one question per post?